# "Failure when receiving data from the peer" в журнале событии Windows

Tags: windows, сервер, https, 1с, iis

Доброго времени суток!

Widnows Server 2016. IIS 10.

Подскажите, где и как я могу отследить событие "Failure when receiving data from the peer" ? Может нужно активировать какие-то логи ? Просмотрел весь журнал событии, но ничего не нашел. Ошибка генерируется при подключении к хранилищу конфигурации 1С. Подключение по https. При пустом хранилище, подключение проходит без проблем. Если же хранилища более весомое по размеру, то вылетает данная ошибка. Вот и хотел отследить проблему. Максимальный размер запросов в настройках IIS уже увеличивал, также timeout.

Comment: Тебе наверное лучше на волшебный форум.

Comment: хотя бы какое событие мне активировать, чтобы поймать ошибку в Windows.?

Comment: Вообще ни разу не 1с-ник, но знаю, что они тусуются на мисте. Ну и винду, как вебстек - ни разу не юзал.

Answer (score 0):

При подключении по https должен быть добавлен сертификат в хранилище сертификатов 1С.
Может быть статья поможет: https://infostart.ru/public/887397/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.